# Split huge sql table logically into smaller tables

Tags: sql, jpa, database-design, database-normalization

I'm making a Spring boot application with Hibernate ORM framework.

I have `Employee` entity there:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String position;

    //// more than 30 private fields

    //// fields related to one sublogic
    private String category;
    private LocalDate categoryAssignmentDate;
    private LocalDate categoryAssignmentDeadlineDate;
    private LocalDate docsSubmitDeadlineDate;
}
```

There are more than 30 private fields in `Employee` class.

And as you can see, I have 4 fields related to same sublogic `Category`.

So my question is: **Is it a good practise to split my `Employee` entity into two entities `Employee` and `Category`, which will be connected as `OnetoOne` relationship?**

Does it make the code clearer?

Comment: Probably, yes. This would be determined by [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). A given attribute column should depend on the primary key of the table alone. If the attribute depends on another attribute, then it belongs in another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [embedded and embeddable](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable) to prevent double table mapping and unnecessary OneToOne relations.

```java
@Entity
public class Employee {
    private String firstName;
    private String position;

    @Embedded
    private Category category
}

@Embeddable
public class Category{
    private String category;
    private LocalDate categoryAssignmentDate;
    private LocalDate categoryAssignmentDeadlineDate;
    private LocalDate docsSubmitDeadlineDate;
}
```

You might need to add [attribute overrides](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable#attribute-overrides)